# PHPMYADMIN Increase Visible Rows

Tags: phpmyadmin, rows

PHPMYADMIN V 4.0.5

Instead of the obligatory 30 rows of visible SQL data, I wish to have 1000 rows per page.

I go to home>settings>main panel>browse mode and set "Maximum number of rows to display" to 1000 but the result then displays from start row 1000 (instead of row 1), and does not retain the setting after logout.

Is there a way to

a) Set (and retain) the start row as 1.
b) Retain the 1000 rows per page view after logout?

Answer (score 1):

About the starting row, the interface in 4.0.x is unclear. You are seeing the correct starting row (as can be seen in the Showing rows top message) but the interface is set to show you the next 1000 rows (when you click on Show).  This has been improved for 4.1.

For the setting to be retained, the easiest way is to set up the phpMyAdmin configuration storage (see http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage).